# Homomorphism from $S_4$ on $Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have just learned about the set of permutations $S_n$. I'm reviewing for the exam and was asked:

> Prove that there are no surjective homomorphisms from $S_4$ to $Z_3$.

What is the idea here?

Comment: @sigmabe: Presumably, writing "on" $\mathbb Z_3$ is a blink-and-you'll-miss-it indication that we're talking about _surjective_ homomorphisms.

Comment: Edited my question to make it clear that we're looking for surjective ones. Why the downvote?

Comment: Hint: does $S_4$ have a *normal* subgroup of order $8$?

Comment: If there were one, where would it send a transposition like (1 2)?.

Comment: Another hint: $S_4$ is generated by the transpositions. Since every transposition has order $2$, what is the only element of $\mathbb Z_3$ it can map to?

Comment: @HenningMakholm. I know that if $a$ in $S_4$ and $t$ is a homomorphism then $t(a)$'s order must divide the order of $a$. In $Z_3$, $ord(0)=1, ord(1)=3, ord(2)=3$, the only order-divisor of $2$ (the order of the transposition) is $0$, so a transposition must be mapped to $0$, correct?

Comment: @TheNotMe: Correct. And since everything in $S_4$ is a product of transpositions ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm And since everything in $S_4$ is a product of transpositions (we learned that!), we have that if $t$ is a homomorphism and $a\in S_4$ where $a=a_1 \cdot ... \cdot a_k$, where $a_i$ is a transposition, then $t(a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_k) = t(a_1) \cdot ... \cdot t(a_k) = 0 +... + 0 = 0$, so the only homomorphism is the trivial one, but that one is not surjective!

Comment: @TheNotMe: Exactly!

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Please write this as an answer so I can accept it!